# Can citric acid create a polyester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, esters

Citric acid has both alcohol and carboxylic acid groups, so could it "esterify" with the other citric acid molecules in solution?

I notice that it is a tertiary alcohol. I don't suppose that would significantly hinder esterification, would it? Then again, it's not as if citric acid simply polymerizes with other citric acid  molecules in solution anyway.

Comment: Tertiary alcohols tend to lose water and produce alkenes, if you press a little too hard. Obtaining the ester you want seems to be possible, but not simple.

Comment: The answer is yes, but you can't make it by normal means because citric acid decomposes to easily. All I did was search on Google for "poly citric acid." You'll find stuff like this: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0011916416301813

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The esterification of carboxylic acids with tertiary alcohols usually occurs by an S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism wherein the oxygen of the alcohol is protonated and a tertiary carbocation is formed. It in turn reacts with the carboxylic acid to form the tertiary ester. The hydroxyl group in citric acid, while tertiary, is alpha to a carboxyl group. A cation alpha to a carboxyl group (-CO<sub>2</sub>H) is a destabilized entity. This mechanism would be precluded. Traditional Fischer esterification is likely sluggish owing to steric hinderance.

[image: SN1 Mechanism]